# module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'verbose'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I can run my program in the terminal, but when I run it directly using Pycharm, it gives

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'verbose'

[image]

Comment: You should copy and paste the code and the error message in the question, rather than uploading a screenshot

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. It worked fine in the PyCharm Community edition, but when I updated to PyCharm Professional I get this same error. As soon as my code tries to "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the code and error message in text form. Only then people will be able to find this through search.

Answer (score 37):

I think I found the answer. I was having the same problem. In PyCharm Professional 2017.3, go to File | Settings | Tools | Python Scientific. There is an option there to "Show plots in toolwindow". Uncheck this option. Then it should work ok. It has something to do with PyCharm trying to help you by allowing you to interact with your plots - as hinted at in this issue discussion. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26652

Comment: While this short-term solution does technically address this specific exception, the underlying issue is matplotlib itself – *not* PyCharm. Matplotlib 2.2.0 accidentally [broke backward compatibility](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10716) in a painful, horrifying manner.

Comment: That was a great find. How did you find this ?

Answer (score 12):

Try to install older version of matplotlib like 2.1.0 rather than v 2.2.0

use:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib==2.1.0
```

Comment: Why would this be a solution? If there is a problem with the latest version of matplotlib, it would be good to know what it is, such that it can be fixed.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest **This is the solution.** Why? Because the most recent stable release of matplotlib *significantly* [broke backward compatibility](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10716) by deleting the long-standing public `matplotlib.verbose` API. This effectively means that *all* downstream applications (like PyCharm) requiring matplotlib as a third-party dependency now need to **blacklist matplotlib 2.2.0** in the hopes that their next stable release will revert this obvious horrifying breakage. In other words, they screwed up. Big time.

Comment: @CecilCurry I completely agree. My comment was inviting to extend the answer as to *why* this is a solution. Since that did not happen, I provided an answer myself.

Comment: **Right.** Thanks for chiming in at [matplotlib#10716](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10716#issuecomment-371662988), too. Excellent work, team.

Answer (score 6):

This is an error on the matplotlib side, `verbose` was unintentionally removed in matplotlib 2.2.0. 
See [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10716).

**This is fixed from the matplotlib side as of version 2.2.2.** (Release [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v2.2.2))

If updating is not an option, one less ideal option could be to locate the `__init__.py` inside the matplotlib folder, and add the line

```
verbose = Verbose()
```

after the `Verbose()` class - that should be around line 384 in the current version.

Comment: For those hitting similar issues in a future timeline, note that the entire `matplotlib.Verbose` API has been deprecated and is expected to be [removed within six months](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10716#issuecomment-371730184). Ergo, [reverting to an older version of matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152936/2809027) is probably the stabler, safer solution.

Comment: Yes, in fact, the solution from this answer (readding verbose to the source) will also cause a warning at every matplotlib import, so it is for sure not a long time solution.

Comment: confirmed - plt is up to par for that and added that line for 2.1.2 in py2.7 py3.6.4 versions.

Comment: @ZF007 This error is now fixed as of version 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is having issue such as: module matplotlib has no attribute 'artist'.
Try this method below by removing matplotlib

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

then reinstall it again worked for me

```
pip install matplotlib==3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent version of PyCharm (Profession 2020.2), this issue if fixed. You can use matplotlib 2.2.0+ and make use of the "Show plots in tool window" feature at the same time.