# How do I get PyCharm to present the graphs I have created rather than the plot object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I have created a histogram in PyCharm but when I execute my code it doesn't produce the graph in IPython.

I have tried to `print(hist)`, I have tried `plt.show()`. I also had this same piece of code work previously so I am a little confused as to what has changed.

```
hist = factor_diff.hist(range=[-0.25, 0.25])
pl.suptitle(peril)
```

I expected to see an interactive plot in IPython with a histogram for each of the columns in `factor_diff` with the range `-0.25` to `0.25`
Instead I got:

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000002780F631C50>
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000002780F6C1518>
```

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: Are you asking about pycharm or IPython. I don't think I grasp in which of those your problem occurs (as the title seems to contradict the main text).

Comment: @DavidG Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am running the python console in PyCharm, which previously has popped up an IPython window with my graphs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the QT_Plugin not having a path correctly assigned.

In order to fix it:

Go to path:

Start -> Edit your environment variables -> Add a new one that is

Variable name: QT_PLUGIN_PATH

Variable value: C:\Users[username] .conda\envs[env]\Library\plugins

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what version of PyCharm you are using. But you might check the File | Settings | Tools | Python Scientific properties. There's a checkbox for "Show plots in tool window" - maybe it's unchecked? There was a period a few months ago where PyCharm and matplotlib were having issues with each other. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146678/module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-verbose/49158765#49158765) for more details.